# How to extract Corresponding td values for a row in a HTML Table

Tags: jquery

I have a HTMl as shown below

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody id="tablebody">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="30%"><b>Screen Name</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="30%"><b>Convinience Charges</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="25%"><b>Minium</b>
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" width="15%"><b>Action</b>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="30%">
                <p>FirstScreen</p>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="30%">
                <p>11</p>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="25%">
                <p>32</p>
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" width="15%"> <a id="566" data-toggle="modal" href="#responsivepopupscreen" class="btn mini green editscreeen"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="30%">
                <p>SeccondScreen</p>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="30%">
                <p>12</p>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="25%">
                <p>56</p>
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" width="15%"> <a id="345" data-toggle="modal" href="#responsivepopupscreen" class="btn mini green editscreeen"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>



    </tbody>
</table>
```

how can i fetch the  value as **FirstScreen , 11  , 32  , anchor id value (566)** when clicked on its corresponding Edit Button

Similarly **SeccondScreen , 12 , 56 ,   anchor id value (345)** when clicked on its corresponding Edit Button

I have tried this way

```
$(document).on("click", ".editscreeen", function (e) {
        $(this).closest.find('<tr>').each(function(){
          var value = $(this).find("p").html();

        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c9qrvrqx/2/

If needed i can add the attributes  for the p tag .
could anybody please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remodel a little bit your script because you have errors inside like closest is a function so it needs to be like this closest(), then you don't add <> to a tr element inside jQuery, you need just tr etc...

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/c9qrvrqx/3/

```
$(document).on("click", ".editscreeen", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td p').each(function(){
          var value = $(this).html();
            alert(value);        
        });
});
```

Or to get all values in array just change the script like this http://jsfiddle.net/c9qrvrqx/7/

```
$(document).on("click", ".editscreeen", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pValue = [];
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td p').each(function(){
          var value = $(this).html();
            pValue.push(value);        
        });
    pValue.push('anchor id value ('+$(this).attr('id')+')' );

    alert(pValue); // Do what you need with the values
});
```

pValue will contain the array in this order

FirstScreen , 11 , 32 , anchor id value (566)  etc..

Comment: Thank you very very much , the first one is fine .

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy when using `.map`, which loop through the selected elements and create an array with the returned value

```
$(document).on("click", ".editscreeen", function (e) {
    var result = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(":last-child")').map(function(){ //Loop all the td except the last child
      return $(this).text(); //Get the text value
    }).get(); //Transform the jQuery array like object into an array

    result.push(this.id); //Add the current anchor id.
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c9qrvrqx/4/

*To remove the white-space, you can use `$.trim()`.*

Answer (score 0):

Please find the Changed Fiddle below

[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/c9qrvrqx/6/)

```
$(document).on("click", "#tablebody tr", function (e) {

    $(this).find('p').each(function(){
      var value = $(this).html();
    alert(value);        
    });
});
```